# PostgreSQL search isn't working

Tags: php, postgresql

**The Problem**

I am creating a search that allows users to see if an enumber is vegan, but no matter what enumber I search, it is simply printing the word vegan when I search for a enumber. i want it to print out what is in the 'vegan' column in the database.

**Code**

```
<?php       
    // Connecting, selecting database
    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=***** port=*****
    dbname=***** user=***** password=*****")
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

    //collect
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        // $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i"."".$searchq);

    // Performing SQL query
    $query = "SELECT vegan FROM enumbers WHERE code LIKE '%$searchq%'";
    $ret = pg_query($dbconn, $query);
   if(!$ret){
      echo pg_last_error($dbconn);
      exit;
   } 
   $output = '';
   while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($ret)){
            $code = $row['code'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $type = $row['type'];
            $vegan = $row['vegan'];

            $output .= '<div> '.vegan.' ';
   }
}
   pg_close($dbconn);

?>
```

Comment: You missed a **$** - try changing  `$output .= '<div>' . $vegan . '</div>'; `

Comment: Also, since this query obviously includes user data, you should be using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never define a variable name `vegan` but want to use it ? (if there's a typo on the line `$output .= '<div> '.vegan.' ';` (missing a $ ?)

And you never push any data in `$output` after setting it.
Should be more like :

```
$output = ''; // there you define it

while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($ret)){
        $code = $row['code'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $type = $row['type'];
        $vegan = $row['vegan'];

        // here you concatenate data

        $output .= "<div>$code / $name / $type / $vegan</div>";
}
echo"Vegan : $output"; // do we have all data ?
```

`$searchq` is never ever controlled and sanitized in your code.

**NEVER** trust user's data coming from inputs !

> you should **really** consider using [PPS : Prepared Parameterized Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This will help [Preventing SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)